# Converting values in column to column headers, and the column headers to values in a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

| University id # | Year | fin_element | prior_year | current_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | element #1 | $1 | $2 |
| 1 | 2022 | element #2 | $3 | $5 |
| 1 | 2022 | element #3 | $2 | $0 |

And I want to convert it to the following using pandas:

| University id # | Year | financial_period | element #1 | element #2 | element #3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | prior_year | $1 | $3 | $2 |
| 1 | 2022 | current_year | $2 | $5 | $0 |

While keeping columns `University #` and `Year` the same, I want the values in column `fin_element` to become the column headers in the new table, and the column headers to become values in a column called `financial_period`.

How can I do this? I have read into pivot, stack and melt, and am a bit overwhelmed since I am new to python and pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
out = (df
       .set_index(['University_id', 'Year', 'fin_element'])
       .stack()
       .unstack(level=2)
       .rename(columns={'level_2' : 'financial_period'})
       .reset_index()
      )
print(out)
```

```
fin_element  University_id  Year financial_period element #1 element #2 element #3
0                        1  2022       prior_year         $1         $3         $2
1                        1  2022     current_year         $2         $5         $0
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! I just added a list comprehension to change the columns names so that 'fin_element' didn't show up in the beginning. Code I used for that: `df.columns = [column for column in df.columns.to_list()]`

Comment: nice! but where does the code you pasted here differ from mine? except level=2 you changed it to the name. What do you mean with list comprehension?

Comment: Oh wow you're quick! I accidentally submitted my comment before I was done completing it.

Comment: still don't get it because your original dataframe has different number of columns than the result at the end, BUT not important. happy it works for you! accept and vote the answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: The example I gave above was a very simplified version of the dataset/problem I was working with. I applied your suggestion within a function, and in there I ended up using the list comprehension. Accepted and voted! Thanks again :)